# What reason can cause StackOverFlowError by Buffered reader in java?

Tags: java, linked-list

There is two files that needed to be read. first file contains only alphabet. Second file contains alphabet and letter. The followng code works well for first file, but wont work for second file. it shows a StackOverFlowError.

```
public void WordLinkedList() throws IOException {
        String book1 = "hemingway_acrosstheriver.txt";
        String book2 = "hemingway_oldman.txt";
        WordList WordList = new WordList("y");
        String[] tokens = new String[30000];
        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("hemingway_acrosstheriver.txt")));
        int g = 0;
        int line = 0;
        for (String m = br.readLine(); m != null; m = br.readLine()) {
            
            
            line++;
            if (g < line) {
                tokens = m.split(" ");

                for (String token : tokens) {
                    WordList.AddWordAtTail(
                            token.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[!\"#$%&'()*+,-._/:;<=>?@\\[\\]^`{|}~]", ""));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }}catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
```

```
public class WordList {

    protected String word;
    protected WordList nextNode;



        public WordList(String word) {
        this.word = word;
        nextNode = null;
            }

    public void AddWordAtTail(WordList end) {
        if (this.nextNode == null) {
            this.nextNode = end;
        } else {
            this.nextNode.AddWordAtTail(end); //this is line 40
        }

        public void AddWordAtTail(String w) { // true
        WordList newNode = new WordList(w);
        if (headNode == null) {
            headNode = newNode;
        } else {
            headNode.AddWordAtTail(newNode);
        }
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at WordList.AddWordAtTail(WordList.java:40)
    at WordList.AddWordAtTail(WordList.java:40)
    at WordList.AddWordAtTail(WordList.java:40)
    at WordList.AddWordAtTail(WordList.java:40)
    at WordList.AddWordAtTail(WordList.java:40)


    }
```

Is it because of the integer that cuase my code not working?

Comment: Take a look at your `AddWordAtTail(WordList end)` method. What happens inside of it when you call it with a non-`null` parameter?

Comment: As an aside `WordList WordList = new WordList("y");` and later `WordList.AddWordAtTail(...);` this is confusing (to a reader it may look like you're calling a static method, for example). Try to stick with java's naming convention, i.e. class names start with an uppercase letter while variable and method names start with a lowercase one. So `WordList wordList = new WordList("y");` and change the method name to `addWordAtTail`.

Comment: It seems that your snippets cannot compile

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with BufferedReader; it is no where in your stacktrace.

The `AddWordAtTail` method will invoke itself on the 'next' node. Meaning, you get a stack as large as the number of words in your `wordList`. Assuming that `hemingway_acrosstheriver.txt` contains quite a few words, that means you're going to run into a stack overflow fairly quickly. Specifically, there are 2 ways to get there:

- some `nextNode` variable points at itself (`nextNode = this;`), or a points at b, b points at c, c points back at a (a loop). In which case no matter how large the stack is, that would never exit, and thus inevitably run out of stack.
- There are more words in the wordList than the stack can handle.

The latter is the likely explanation here.

You could give yourself more stack with `java -Xss128m` or some such, but perhaps it's a better idea to fix the code so that it doesn't require stack. Recursion is usually a bad solution; at the very least, one that is likely to run into this problem. Simply - stop using it.

```
WordList current = this;
while (current.nextNode != null) current = current.nextNode;
current.nextNode = end;
```

This accomplishes the same goal without eating up any stack at all.